# Access an array or a variable inside a function from the main in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, function, arraylist

for the given simple code for Binary Search

```
public static int binsearch(int [] a,int low, int high, int val) {
     ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();

     if(a.length == 0)
       return -1;

     if(high < low)
       return -1;

     int mid = (low+high)/2;

     arr.add(mid);

     if(a[mid] == val)
       return mid;

     else if(val > a[mid])
        return binsearch(a,mid+1,high,val);

     else
        return binsea

     binsearch(a,low,mid-1,val);

    }
```

I have initialized an Arraylist inside the function. How can I access that ArrayList from the main, if I want to in JAVA. Because this function returns the index of the number in the array if present and not the Arraylist.

Comment: You can't access directly, since it's method local. You can make it static in the class. Or return it with the index.

Comment: Define your ArrayList elsewhere outside this method? You're being limited by the scope of that variable.

Comment: Super basic stuff, asked a zillion times and explained in any good book.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the `ArrayList` within the method, you can pass it to the method:

```
public static int binsearch(int [] a,int low, int high, int val, List<Integer> arr) {
    if(a.length == 0)      
        return -1;

     if(high < low)               
         return -1;
     ...
}
```

and call the method from `main` with:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int index = binsearch(a,0, a.length, value, list);
```

After the call you'll have access to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Declare array list as global variable and add values inside function `binsearch()`

```
public class test{

static ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    binsearch(.... pass values);

    //you can access array list here
}

public static int binsearch(int [] a,int low, int high, int val) {
    if(a.length == 0)
        return -1;

    if(high < low)
        return -1;

    int mid = (low+high)/2;

    arr.add(mid);

    if(a[mid] == val)
        return mid;
    else if(val > a[mid])
        return binsearch(a,mid+1,high,val);
    else
        return binsearch(a,low,mid-1,val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the array list globally, since it's within the scope of function so it won't be accessible.

Make `ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList();` the attribute of class.